# ProtectKeyWithTPM method of the Win32_EncryptableVolume class causes exception

Tags: c#, encryption, bitlocker

I want to try encrypt a logical disk volume containing the OS's installation using the encrypt method of the [Win32_EncryptableVolume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376483(v=vs.85).aspx) class. Before I use this method, I have to create a key to protect this volume and for this I have several options, but if I want to encrypt the logical disk volume containing the OS's installation I have to use the [ProtectKeyWithTPM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376470(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

The problem happens when I try to call `ProtectKeyWithTPM` method, it returns to me the following stack trace:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BE)
    em System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
    em System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, ManagementBaseObject inParameters, InvokeMethodOptions options)
    em ListDrivers.BitLocker.callMethod(String method, ManagementObject privateLateBoundObject, ManagementBaseObject inParams) na C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BitlockerTeste\BitlockerTeste\BitLocker.cs:linha 221
    em ListDrivers.BitLocker.defineTPM(String id, ArrayList drivers) na C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BitlockerTeste\BitlockerTeste\BitLocker.cs:linha 149
    em ListDrivers.Program.<TPMProtection>d__8.MoveNext() na C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BitlockerTeste\BitlockerTeste\Program.cs:linha 275
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
    em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    em ListDrivers.Program.<encryptMenu>d__7.MoveNext() na C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BitlockerTeste\BitlockerTeste\Program.cs:linha 241
```

This error only happens on this method, all other `Win32_EncryptableVolume` methods works normally, I've searched in many sites a solution for this, but I didn't find nothing to help.

My question is, why this happens when I try to protect the volume with TPM. Why all other protection methods that don't use TPM works normally.

Edit:

`defineTPM` method:

```
public static UInt32 defineTPM(string id, ArrayList drivers)
{
   String deviceId = findByDriverLetter(id, drivers);
   if (deviceId != null)
   {
       ManagementObject privateLateBoundObject = returnManagementObjectForDevice(deviceId);
       ManagementBaseObject inParams = null;
       return callMethod("ProtectKeyWithTPMandStartupKey", privateLateBoundObject, inParams);
   }
   return Convert.ToUInt32(2147942487);
}
```

`callMethod` method:

```
private static UInt32 callMethod(String method, ManagementObject privateLateBoundObject, ManagementBaseObject inParams)
{
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = privateLateBoundObject.InvokeMethod(method, inParams, null);
    return Convert.ToUInt32(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value);
}
```

Comment: The code 0x800706BE looks like to be some generic error. Could the `COMException` be related to the wrong case-sensitive method name you are invoking? Or perhaps you must explicitly declare `out` parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sugested in comments of you question, you **MUST** explicitly declare the `inParams`, even if you are not passing any value.

```
ManagementBaseObject inParams;
inParams = PrivateLateBoundObject.GetMethodParameters("ProtectKeyWithTPM");
```

For a complete mapping of `Win32_EncryptableVolume` class take a look at https://github.com/Internet2/incert/blob/baf2ab60299df1dcd93192da7600342dda2497ad/Windows/Engine/NativeCode/Wmi/EncryptableVolume.cs